# How do I carry out this numpy array manipulation efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am given with an array such as:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I am also given another array with all the entries greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of `a`. An example:

```
array_index = numpy.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 1, 3]])
```

`array_index` basically tells where I should stack the elements of `a` to. For example first entry of `array_index` `[0, 0, 1, 2]` tells that index 0 element of fist entry of `a` should stay the same, second index 0 tells that index 1 element of `a` should be stacked to index 0, third index 1 tells that index 2 element of `a` should be stacked to index 1, and so on.
Now I need to construct another array of the same shape as that of `my_array` such that the entries are the respective index value of `a` at `array_index`. In this case I would have first

```
array_desired = numpy.zeros(array_index.shape)
```

And I would fill in the values like:

```
array_desired = [[a[0]+a[1], a[2], a[3], 0], [a[0], a[1], a[2]+a[3], 0],
                 [a[0], a[1]+a[2], 0, a[3]]]
```

To do this, as a first approach I constructed the following for the 0th element:

```
stack_index = numpy.where(array_index == 0)
array_desired[stack_index] += a[stack_index]
print(array_desired)
>>> [[1 2 0 0] [1 0 0 0] [1 0 0 0]]
```

which is something, but not exactly what I wanted:

```
>>>[[3 0 0 0][1 0 0 0][1 0 0 0]]
```

Any idea on how to achieve proper stacking by index as I described above?

**Update:**

I have a method that works for first index now:

```
temp_array = numpy.zeros(array_index.shape)
stack_index = numpy.where(array_index == 0)
temp_array[stack_index] = a[stack_index]
n = np.sum(temp_array, axis=(1))
array_desired[:,0]= n
```

But, this method would still require me to loop over each index. I would like to have something more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

Here's your sample data:

```
In [98]: a
Out[98]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [99]: array_index
Out[99]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 3]])
```

Create `b` to hold the result, and do the sum using `np.add.at`.  `row_index` is just the 3x1 array `[[0], [1], [2]]`.

```
In [100]: b = np.zeros_like(a)

In [101]: row_index = np.arange(array_index.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)

In [102]: np.add.at(b, (row_index, array_index), a)

In [103]: b
Out[103]: 
array([[3, 3, 4, 0],
       [1, 2, 7, 0],
       [1, 5, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: How would this method generalise? For example if the shape of `a` and `array_index` is `(10, 15)`?

Comment: It should work without any changes.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah. I tried it, and it did not work as expected. My try was specifically for arrays of size `(8, 4)`.

Comment: There is probably something different about what you tried that doesn't match the description in the question.  For example, with size (8, 4), are all the values in `array_index` between 0 and 3 (inclusive)?

Comment: Yes. They are between 0 and 3 inclusive.

Comment: I just tried examples with sizes (10, 15) and (8, 4), and both worked.  Something that could go wrong is if `a` is an array of 8 bit integers, and the values that are added to create `b` overflow (in which case the overflowed values will "wrap around").  To avoid that, you could create `b` using, for example, `b = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=int)` instead of `b = np.zeros_like(a)`.

Comment: Here is a detailed code which explains what I am saying: [link[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319524/why-am-i-getting-different-output-for-two-function-which-are-supposed-to-be-seem?noredirect=1#comment87654786_50319524)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code discussed in *this* question works in the general case.  There is more going on in the code in the other question, so there are more places for bugs (e.g. is your reshaping correct?).  I recommend trying that code with even smaller examples--something small enough that it is not hard to figure out the correct result by hand--and then checking the results in the intermediate steps of the two functions to see if you are computing what you expected to compute.